# Docker console output as a log, not as a pseudo-GUI

Tags: docker

Many Docker commands show something that in the lack of a better word I'd call a "pseudo-GUI" on the console, like for example Docker build. This GUI is staying at the same position on the console and updating live:

[image]

I'd rather like to have a simple stream of output, like it is written by most console applications. Means no control characters, no colors, just writing line after line.

Is there a command option to do so on the Docker CLI?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior of [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/). To achieve the desired output, use `--progress=plain` when building the image:

```bash
$ docker build --progress-plain ...
```

or you can disable `BUILDKIT` altogether for the build:

```bash
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The change in output format happened because BuildKit is now the default builder in Docker (as of version 23.0).

You can add `--progress=plain` to your docker command to have the output stream in a simpler format.

If you want to set that as the default, you can set the `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` environment variable to `plain` in your shell startup file.

You can opt out of using BuildKit by setting the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` to `0`. Then it'll use the legacy builder and the output will look like you're used to. I won't recommend this though and the legacy builder will likely be removed in a future version of Docker.